# Difficulty with Linq on inner and left outer joins

Tags: c#, linq, left-join

I can't see why this fails. The error is:

> Failure: Identifier 'Patient_recid' is not a parameter or variable or field of 'Nova.Data.Returntooffice'. If 'Patient_recid' is a property please add the FieldAlias or Storage attribute to it or declare it as a field's alias.

Yep...that is correct. The tables are set up such that

1. `Returntooffices` references an `encountertimes` record (inner join).
2. The `encountertimes` record references `patient` table record (inner join).
3. The `Returntoooffice` record may or may not have an `appointment` record --This is the reason I am trying to use a left outer join.

The `returntooffices` record DOES NOT have a `patient_recid`, and this is why I am attempting to join it to a `encountertimes` record.

How is this done correctly?

TIA

```
var query = 
    from rto in cxt.Returntooffices
    from encounter in cxt.Encountertimes.Where(f => f.Recid == rto.Encounter_recid)
    from patient in cxt.Patients.Where(p => p.Recid == encounter.Patient_recid && p.Groupid == groupid)
    from appointment in cxt.Appointments.Where(a => a.Recid == rto.Appointment_recid).DefaultIfEmpty()
    select new
    {
        RTO = rto,
        APPOINTMENT = appointment
     };

 var b = query.ToList();
```

Comment: Is this linq to entities with already specified relationships, or tables without foreign keys?

Comment: @JNYRanger The references are foreign keys from existing tables of the database. (cxt is the references to the database namespace). Thanks.

Comment: @JNYRanger The real problem is that I need a left outer join on the appointment table. (Doing this with all inner joins runs without error). :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In lieu of a better idea, this seems to compile and work (yea!)

```
var q = 
    from rto in cxt.Returntooffices
    join encounter in cxt.Encountertimes on rto.Encounter_recid equals encounter.Recid 
    join patient in cxt.Patients on encounter.Patient_recid equals patient.Recid
    join appointment in cxt.Appointments on rto.Appointment_recid equals appointment.Recid into apt
    from a in apt.DefaultIfEmpty() 
    where patient.Groupid == groupid
    select new
     {
        RTO = rto,
        APPOINTMENT = a
      }
    ).ToList();
```

Comment: I just saw your comments.  What you posted here should do the trick, and your final join should in fact do a left outer join.  One thing to note is that you shouldn't combine query syntax with lambda syntax, which you did in your question, but properly avoided here.